# Image in android?

Tags: android, image, performance, android-layout, android-studio

My `ImageButton` in my app is very tiny and cut off. I realized this could be because the image was in the `drawable` folder instead of the mitmap folders. So, I copied the images from the `drawable` folder, and pasted them in `mitmap` folders. Now, should I go about deleting the image from the `drawable` folder? I get the following saying it is not safe:

[image]

I know how to access the images, but should I delete them from the drawable folder now that I have already moved them to the mitmaps? If I do a delete anyway, will I need to alter my code to access the mitmap image? What is safest to do?

Here is an image of my mitmaps:
[image]

Thanks for the expert advice,
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Not safe" in this context just means that it's still being used somewhere.  If you delete it, the current usage will fail to compile, and you'll be easily able to find and alter it to point at the new location.

Comment: Okay, so I have already pasted the picture into my mitmaps. So it's okay to delete the original in the drawable folder? Here is a screen shot of the mitmaps:
http://snag.gy/MXS1o.jpg

Comment: Yes, it's OK.  As I said, you might still have references to it, but deleting it from the folder is the only way to find out -- if you can't solve the resulting compile problem, you can easily just add it back in by copying back from the drawable folder.  As an aside, if you're this nervous about making minor changes to your project, you should really learn how to use Git or some other version control software, so you can easily undo changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely delete this image, in **Android Studio** if you are using this image or else the file will be open at some place, you can get this error actually, so try deleting this image will safely remove the only selected image into your workspace. So hassle free to delete it.

After deleting your image, clear your project and run it, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The mipmap folder is used for image that are very small and should be used in the action bar, and other menus. If you find your image too tiny, it just will be worst if you put it in the mipmap folder. If it's tiny although the image is in the drawable folder, maybe the image has a very small dimension or your imageview is too small.